# Interesting SQL quiz

Tags: sql

Recently I came across with the following quiz. Imagine we have this table

```
+--------+
| colors |
+--------+
| red    |
| black  |
| white  |
| green  |
| orange |
+--------+
```

The task is to write a SQL query that will select all pairs without allowing duplicates. Permutations are counted too ({red, black} = {black, red}, hence only one of the pair is allowed).

Comment: are you looking for ANSI SQL or can it be DBMS specific (ex. SQL Server)?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try this

```
Select A.Color, B.Color
From Colors A
Cross Join Colors B
Where A.Color > B.Color
```

Comment: Black = Black would be false, therefore it wouldt get selected.  The above query looks good to me

Comment: Here is an interesting link on CROSS JOINS

http://www.databasejournal.com/sqletc/article.php/1438121/Generate-Test-Data-Quickly-with-Cross-Joins.htm

Comment: @glaz, because a cross join means take every element in Set A and pair it with every element in Set B... So you get every possible ordered combination. The Where clause predicate just eliminates the ones where the element pairs are from the same element, and one of the duplicates... (A, B) and (B, A)

Answer (score 0):

```
Select A.Colors, B.Colors From Colors A 
Cross Join Colors B Where A.Colors < B.Colors or B.colors < A.colors
```

Comment: This would violate the pre-condition about permutations: `{red, black} = {black, red}, hence only one of the pair is allowed`.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
Select * From colours A 
Cross Join colours B Where A.colours < B.colours or B.colours > A.colours
and b.colours != b.colours and a.colours != a.colours
```